# Logrotate doesn't rotate logs

Tags: logrotate

I want to use [logrorate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html). The logs are written to `/var/log/curLog/log.log`. As mentioned in the documentation, I create a new file in `/etc/logrotate.d/` with name `currentLog`. The content of `currentLog` is:

```
/var/log/curLog/log.log{
    size 100k,
    rotate 10,
    daily,
    compress,
    notifempty
    missingok
}
```

But the logs increase above the 100k size, and nothing happens.
Should I restart some service or do some other operations?

Comment: No logrotate runs with cron not as a deamon. That article may help:http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/sample-logrotate-configuration-and-troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options that dictate the when the rotation occurs.

```
size 100k   # if size > 100k
daily       # once a day
notifempty  # not if == 0k
```

Remove the `daily` and it should occur more regularly when the file is > 100k

Second, If the process that creates the log file is a daemon that keeps the file open, you will most likely need to restart that process or at least signal it to open a new log file once logrotate has moved the old one.

For example, Apache httpd can graciously reload config and reopen log files with the `kill -SIGUSR1 <pid>` or `/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful` command rather than being completely restarted.

```
postrotate
        /usr/sbin/apachectl graceful > /dev/null
endscript
```